# segmentation fault when trying to display a list

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to display a list in C but when I do it I'm getting a segfault. Valgrind is telling me that it's because I'm trying to reach uninitialized values, can you help me?

Function to display the list (segfault at line 7):

```
void display_list(struct list *list)
{
    struct list *tmp;

    tmp = list;
    my_printf("liste =");    
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        my_printf(" %d", tmp->number);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    my_printf("\n");
    free(tmp);
}
```

Structure of the list:

```
struct list
{
    int number;
    struct list_a *next;
};
```

main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct list *list_a;
    struct list *list_b;
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        add_item(&list_a, my_getnbr(argv[i]));
    }
    display_list(list_a);
    free(list_a);
    free(list_b);
    return (0);
}
```

```
int add_item(struct list **list, int item)
{
    struct list *element = malloc (sizeof(*element));

    if (element == NULL)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    element->number = item;
    element->next = *list;
    *list = element;
    return (0);
}
```

```
int my_getnbr(char const *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    int nbr = 0;

    if (str[0] == '-' && str[1] != '\0')
        i++;
    for (i; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9')
            write(2, "there must be only numbers in the string", 40);
        nbr = nbr + str[i] - 48;
        nbr = nbr * 10;
    }
    nbr = nbr / 10;
    if (str[0] == '-')
        return (-1 * nbr);
    else
        return (nbr);
}
```

Comment: You didn't disclose `add_item` (looks important), `my_printf`, and `my_getnbr`. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Actually `list_a` is uninitialized. It seems you should initialize that. Also `list_b` is used without being initialized.

Comment: free(list_b); is invalid, since it is uninitialized

Comment: @ViscloDev This declaration struct list
{
    int number;
    struct list_a *next;
}; does not make a sense.

Comment: element->next = *list; does not make sense. list is empty at this point and you cant use it. Also having a variable name same as the type "list" is really bad.

Comment: regarding: `struct list
{
    int number;
    struct list_a *next;
};`  This should be: `struct list
{
    int number;
    struct list *next;  // notice no `_a`
};`

Comment: in function: `display_list()` this statement: `free(tmp);` does nothing because the prior code has already set `tmp` to NULL

Comment: regarding: `write(2, "there must be only numbers in the string", 40);`  this is an unrecoverable error, so why continue to execute the function?

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (element == NULL)
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);`  Should inform the user of this error.  Suggest: `if (element == NULL) { perror( "malloc failed" );
        return (EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: in function: `int my_getnbr()`  suggest greatly simplifying the code by using `strtol()`  Which also reports when an error occurred

Comment: OT: in function: `main()`, this statement; `add_item(&list_a, my_getnbr(argv[i]));` is failing to check the returned value from: `my_getnbr()`  so `main()` does not know if the operation was successful or not

Comment: in function: `main()` regarding; `struct list *list_a;
    struct list *list_b;`  those pointers will contain what every trash is on the stack at their location.  Any called function will be unable to determine if it is adding the first node or some following node.  This is a good way to crash the program.  Suggest: `struct list *list_a = NULL;
    struct list *list_b = NULL;`

Comment: regarding: `free(list_a);
    free(list_b);`  These are trying to pass the contents of the pointers on the stack, in `main()` however, first need to free() each of the nodes in the respective linked list

Comment: OT:  regarding: `nbr = nbr + str[i] - 48;`  using 'magic' numbers is a very poor programming practice.  Suggest: `nbr = nbr + str[i] - '0';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main` function, you're calling `free` on `list_b`, but it is uninitialized meaning its valid is **indeterminate**.  Attempting to call `free` on such a pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which causes a crash.

Get rid of that call to `free`, and in fact remove `list_b` entirely as it isn't being used.

Also, calling `free` at the end of `display_list` doesn't make sense because you don't need to clean up any memory here.  You get away with it because the value of `tmp` is NULL at this point, and calling `free` on a NULL pointer is a no-op.

You also have `list_a` uninitialized.  This results in your list having an invalid pointer at the end.  You should initialize it to NULL.